# Setting custom ToolTip for Border Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, internationalization

I am working on internationalizing a WPF application. I am stuck at a situation where a ToolTip to be set near a border control which is to be concatenated like this:

`RoleType : Manager`

I am binding RoleType in ViewModel which has Manager, TechLead, Engineer etc. RoleType string is fixed and is translated in Resources file. Now in view, I need to concatenate and show the user who has logged in.

I tried MultiBinding but after login, my screen turns blackout. I cannot exit my application.

Here is the code I am trying:

```xaml
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="auto" Width="auto" 
             Background="Transparent" >
        <Border.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} : {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="{languageTranslation:Translate RoleType}" />
                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="{languageTranslation:Translate {Binding UserName}}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border.ToolTip>
        <ContentControl Height="65" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserProfileIcon}"></ContentControl>
    </Border>
```

What am I doing wrong? Converters are not required as it is only strings.

Comment: `ElementName` in a Binding usually points to a FrameworkElement within the same scope. `languageTranslation:Translate` looks like a custom markup. Did you write that yourself or are you using a framework for that?

Comment: @Manfred Its a custom framework used in our company.

Comment: Then you might want to look for errors or proper usage there. We don't have access to that. If this only happens with ToolTips (and other elements that have a separate VisualTree, like ContextMenus) your problem might be the Bindings, because they would be out of scope.

Comment: Also, please try to reduce your example to the minimal possible code that causes this problem. Does it happen if the TextBlock is not within a tooltip? Does it happen if you only bind one of the values (no MultiBinding)? Both or just one of them? etc.

Comment: If I bind one value that is type of user which comes from the viewmodel, its fine. But I need to show the tooltip as concatenated version.

Comment: I just doubt that the concatenation (via MultiBinding) is the problem. It would be a very strange bug if it only happens if you use a MultiBinding within a ToolTip. Try only using the second binding (without the multibinding) and see if the problem persists. This line looks suspiciously like unintended usage: `ElementName="{languageTranslation:Translate {Binding UserName}}"`.